# Picture not found in moderncv class

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

I try to compile the following simple template with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual}         

\title{your Curriculum Vitae title}
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Lastname}
\mobile{Mobile}
\phone{Phone}
\email{Email}
\homepage{Homepage}
\extrainfo{Extra Info}
\photo[64pt]{picture}
\quote{Subtitle}
\address{Address}{City, Country}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section Name}
\cvline{Subject}{Description.}
\cventry{Time}{Position}{Company Name}{City}{Country}{Description}
\cvcomputer{Skill}{Description}{Skill}{Description}
\cvlanguage{Language}{Proficiency}{Description} 

\end{document}
```

However I always get the following error message: ! LaTeX Error: File `picture' not found.
I have a file picture.eps as well as a file picture in the same directory, so not sure why
I get this error message. Anyone an idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are processing with `pdflatex` you should convert `picture.eps` into `picture.pdf`. There are many tools for doing it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation depends on your LaTeX Distribution. First of all the package [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) is the main key. It allows the including of encapsulated postscript (eps) by running `pdflatex`.

If you are using [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) or newer the following changes is important:

> `pdf(LA)TEX` now automatically converts a requested Encapsulated
>   PostScript (EPS) file to PDF, via the [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) package, when and if
>   the LATEX `graphics.cfg` configuration file is loaded, and PDF is being
>   output. The default options are intended to eliminate any chance of
>   hand-created PDF files being overwritten, but you can also prevent
>   [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) from being loaded at all by putting
>   `\newcommand{\DoNotLoadEpstopdf}{}` (or `\def...`) before the
>   `\documentclass` declaration. It is also not loaded if the `pst-pdf`
>   package is used. For more details, see the [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) package
>   documentation.